# Mostrar diferentes datos con un if en un echo

Tags: php, html

```html
<tbody>
 <?php while($datos=$resultado->fetch_array()){?>
  <tr class="row100 body">
   <td class="cell100 column1"><?php echo $datos['nombre']." ".$datos['apellido'] ?></td>
   <td class="cell100 column2"><?php echo $datos['telefono'];?></td>
   <td class="cell100 column3"><?php echo $datos['correo'];?></td>
   <td class="cell100 column4"><?php echo $datos['tipo'];?></td>
```

Tengo este pedazo de codigo donde muestro unos datos de mi base de datos pero tengo el problema en el campo tipo, en mi campo tipo tengo tres números 1, 2 o 3; el 1 es para gerente, el 2 para vendedor y el 3 para vendedor comisionista.

Tengo pensado con un if de que si es 1 muestre lo mencionado arriba, pero no tengo idea de donde o como implementar el if, espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor que un `if` puede utilizar `switch`

```
    <tbody>
        <?php while($datos=$resultado->fetch_array()){?>
            <tr class="row100 body">
                <td class="cell100 column1"><?php echo $datos['nombre']." ".$datos['apellido'] ?></td>
                <td class="cell100 column2"><?php echo $datos['telefono'];?></td>
                <td class="cell100 column3"><?php echo $datos['correo'];?></td>
                <td class="cell100 column4">
    <?php
     switch($datos['tipo']){
    case 1: echo "gerente"; break;
    case 2: echo "vendedor "; break;
    case 3: echo "comisionista"; break;
    }

    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, se pudo resolver el problema que tenía.